# Mono WebSocket server freezes for 5 minutes

Tags: c#, websocket, mono, freeze

My C# WebSocket server app (with around ~100-200 clients) randomly freezes for 5-10 minutes. Then unfreezes itself. It happens only on Linux while running on Mono. On Windows everything works fine.

I've found a very old thread with the same problem & solution, but I'm not sure how exactly I should edit the Socket.cs on Mono to fix this. ([Mono app freezes at non-blocking socket send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477078/mono-app-freezes-at-non-blocking-socket-send)).

If somebody could help me I'd be very thankful =)

Comment: check how many sockets are open/established  at the moment your server hangs: https://serverfault.com/a/997199/186958 also a bit old but maybe worth reading as a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616 to get an idea where to look for.

Comment: Instead of running on Mono, migrate to .NET Core and see what you get there.

Comment: I can confirm that migrating to .NET Core was the solution for me.. Everything works fine now even under Linux